# Whats the best solution to Entity Framework cores lack of moderate LINQ query support?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

So basically I have a table containing a set of data. This data is then joined onto an organisation table to which multiple users can be apart of. Im then trying to get all files in the table where the user executing the query, has permission to access the organisation. To do this I'm using a where clause that checks the users permissions from the application, to the files that have them organisations linked. Im then selecting the top 100 results and counting the records returned. (I want to see if the user has access to 100+ files over all the organisations).

The problem is when I use the following LINQ query:

```
(from f in File
 join o in Organisation on f.OrganisationId equals o.Id
 where permissions.Contains(o.Id.ToString())
 select f).Take(100).Count();
```

The `take` and the `count` aren't executed on the SQL server and are run in memory when I try a contains on a list which should convert to an `IN (VALUES)` query on SQL. I have 70,000+ File records and this is very slow and times out on a web server. This is expected as Entity Framework core is in early stages and does not support moderate or advanced LINQ queries yet.

My question is, is there a better alternative to raw SQL queries while still being able to filter by an array of items and still using Entity Framework core v1.1? Thanks.

Edit: I tried updating to the latest version, this still did not solve my issue as I still got the following output.

```
The LINQ expression '{permissions => Contains([o].Id.ToString())}' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
The LINQ expression 'Contains([o].Id.ToString())' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
The LINQ expression 'Take(__p_1)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

Comment: It translates to SQL in my test (EF Core v1.1.1)

Comment: Ah this is promising news! I didn't realize that a hotfix was released. I'm currently running 1.1.0 so I'll try upgrade and get back to you. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve my issue.

Comment: Is this the real query? And what is the type of `permissions` variable?

Comment: That's the real query with different variable names. `permissions` is an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Does Organisation.Id is also string? And btw why you join Organisation table, you already have OrganisationId in File table so you can do something like this `File.where(f => permissions.Contains(f.OrganisationId )).Take(100).Count();`

Comment: Its for another join that's not relevant to this issue. I've removed everything and found that the `IEnumerable` is causing the query not to convert correctly. And no the Id is an `int` thus I use `.ToString()` but again , to my knowledge, this isn't relevant to the translation.

Comment: @KieranDevlin Try doing `var permissions2 = permissions.ToArray()` and then use `permissions2`.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that in the past, Ive also tried `ToList`, It seems that collections just aren't supported in LINQ to SQL yet.

Comment: Every detail is important ([mcve]). In my test, the `o.Id` is `int`, `permissions` are `IEnumerable<int>`, and the result is `SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [f].[Id], [f].[Name], [f].[OrganisationId]
    FROM [Files] AS [f]
    INNER JOIN [Organisations] AS [o] ON [f].[OrganisationId] = [o].[Id]
    WHERE [o].[Id] IN (1, 3, 4)
) AS [t]` with no warnings. Most likely the `o.Id.ToString()` is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warnings are misleading - the problem is the `ToString()` call which causes client evaluation of the query.

The following should produce the intended SQL query:

```
var idList = permissions.Select(int.Parse);
var result = (
    from f in File
    join o in Organisation on f.OrganisationId equals o.Id
    where idList.Contains(o.Id)
    select f).Take(100).Count();
```

which in my environment (EF Core v1.1.1) produces the following SQL with no warnings (as expected):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [f].[Id], [f].[Name], [f].[OrganisationId]
    FROM [Files] AS [f]
    INNER JOIN [Organisations] AS [o] ON [f].[OrganisationId] = [o].[Id]
    WHERE [o].[Id] IN (1, 3, 4)
) AS [t]
```

Comment: Thanks, I owe you a beer.